# Loading chart via Angular ngRoute not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I am trying to load a chart (highcharts library) via `angular` `ngRoute`, but I cannot display the chart.

JS - this is my config

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [
     'ngRoute'
     ]);

      app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
       templateUrl: 'some.html',
       controller: 'MainCtrl'
       })
       .when('/contacts/:_id', {
       templateUrl: 'contacts/some.html',
       controller: 'SecondCtrl'
       })
       .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
       });


      });
```

JS - these are my controllers

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
// some code here
}]);

app.controller('SecondCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
//some code here
// drawing chart function
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            //rest of the code
}]);
```

HTML 
                 //contacts/some.html page

No errors in the console, though the chart is not loading

Loading on the main page - index.html only if to write

```
<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you div is empty? Maybe it's populated but there are some css problems? Check chrome dev tool

Comment: Yes, it's empty, I think that the problem is within routing

Comment: It was css problems:) thanks. chart is displayed only behind bootstrap divs, now exploring how to fix it. Thanks a lot

Comment: btw avoid using `$(function () { $('#container').highcharts({ }) });` it's - old, unelegant, dirty, bad, not-angular-way, spaghetti code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a directive "chart" and use $element in the link function to initiate the Highchart object. Something as shown below:

```
app.directive("chart", function () {
return {
    template: '<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto"></div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        data: "=" // two way binding
    },
    replace: true,
    controller: 'CustomCtrl',
    link: function ($scope, element, $attrs) {

            var mapChart = $(element).highcharts('Area', {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: $(element).attr('id')
                },series: [
                {
                    name: 'Countries',
                    mapData: mapData,
                    color: '#E0E0E0',
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                },/* so on */
```

And in your html page add below line

```
    <div class="container" ng-controller="CustomCtrlas customCtrl">
       <chart class="container" data='customCtrl.chartData'>
    </div>
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks, it works, though the main reason was in css:) chart is not displaying in bootstrap divs, only behind them, exploring how to fix it